# How to write multiple rows in column excel python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlrd, geopy

I have 'column A' contains Hotel Name, i want to write 'loc.address' for each hotel at 'column B' in excel

ex:

[image: This should it look like]

i use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import xlrd

# Give the location of the file
loc = "C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/test.xlsx"


# To open Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    hotel_column = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="abd")
    
    loc = geolocator.geocode(hotel_column, country_codes='', language='')
    if loc is None:
        print('Cant find latitude & longitude of this place :(')
    else:
        print("latitude is :", loc.latitude, "\nlongitude is:", loc.longitude)
        print('Location Address: ' + loc.address)
        print('---------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: You need to find and install some third-party module that make it possible for you read and write Excel files.

Comment: I just need to loop over cells in specific column and enter data

Comment: Entering data will require at least modifying some in-memory representation of the sheet regardless of whether you write the final results to a file. A module that allows both reading and writing Excel data should support doing this.

Comment: can't you create a new excel file or overwrite the existing one?

Comment: I  need just how to loop over cell in column to write data

Comment: @AbdullahMd I posted an answer using openpyxl that can help you achieve the update. I noticed that you reused the variable loc that's why I hardcoded the file read and save, but you can fix that and use a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openpyxl` can update xlsx files

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import xlrd
import openpyxl

# To open Workbook
loc = "C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/test.xlsx"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

locs=[]
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    hotel_column = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="abd")
    
    loc = geolocator.geocode(hotel_column, country_codes='', language='')
    if loc is None:
        print('Cant find latitude & longitude of this place :(')
        locs.append('Cant find latitude & longitude of this place :(')
    else:
        print("latitude is :", loc.latitude, "\nlongitude is:", loc.longitude)
        print('Location Address: ' + loc.address)
        print('---------------------------------------------------')
        locs.append('Location Address: ' + loc.address)

xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/test.xlsx")
sheet = xfile.worksheets[0]

for i,val in enumerate(locs):
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value = val
xfile.save('C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/test.xlsx')
```

Comment: @Jeyvee AttributeError: 'Location' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @AbdullahMd method append is being used only in locs which is a list created just before the reading loop, I just tried the code myself and can't reproduce the error. If you adapted this code please make sure locs is defined as list and that you are appending strings to it.

Comment: if i want to print loc.latitude for each hotel how can do that?

Comment: you can populate the list locs with "latitude is: " + str(loc.latitude)